# MySQL - Use column from one table if it exists, or else take it from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, datatables

I am looking for a MySQL query that would do the following.

I have 2 tables with the same structure, where the key is the first 4 fields:

```
Table 1:
|   DATE    |  TYPE  |  CITY  |  ID   |  AMOUNT |
|2018-01-01 |  SALE  |  NYC   |  001  |  10.00  |
|2018-01-05 |  PURCH |  LA    |  002  |  15.00  |
|2018-01-08 |  SALE  |  LA    |  001  |  17.00  |
|2018-02-09 |  PURCH |  NYC   |  002  |  12.00  |

Table 2:
|   DATE    |  TYPE  |  CITY  |  ID   |  AMOUNT |
|2018-01-01 |  SALE  |  NYC   |  001  |  11.00  |
|2018-01-05 |  PURCH |  LA    |  002  |  14.00  |
|2018-01-08 |  SALE  |  LA    |  001  |  16.00  |
|2018-02-09 |  PURCH |  NYC   |  002  |  13.00  |
|2018-05-01 |  SALE  |  WASH  |  004  |  11.00  |
|2018-08-08 |  SALE  |  NYC   |  001  |  12.00  |
```

And I want a single view/query with the result from table1 if it exists and from table2 if it doesn't exist in table1 with the same key. In this example, the first 4 lines of table1 and the last 2 lines of table 2 would be included:

```
|   DATE    |  TYPE  |  CITY  |  ID   |  AMOUNT |
|2018-01-01 |  SALE  |  NYC   |  001  |  10.00  |
|2018-01-05 |  PURCH |  LA    |  002  |  15.00  |
|2018-01-08 |  SALE  |  LA    |  001  |  17.00  |
|2018-02-09 |  PURCH |  NYC   |  002  |  12.00  |
|2018-05-01 |  SALE  |  WASH  |  004  |  11.00  |
|2018-08-08 |  SALE  |  NYC   |  001  |  12.00  |
```

Table 2 doesn't necessarily contain all keys from table1, so a left join on table2 wouldn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily accomplished with `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
union all
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 t1
                  where t1.date = t2.date and
                        t1.type = t2.type and
                        t1.city = t2.city and
                        t1.id = t2.id
                 );
```